# How to make my System close and re-open automatically?

Tags: vb.net

Im making a system, and as part of the system i need to have a reset function. I have tried Application.reset, environment and shell, but nothing seems to be working with the 2017 VB.net console app?

Answer (score 0):

Just run the program and let the current instance exit. Warning: don't run this example. It'll create and endless loop of spawned processes.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Process.Start("ConsoleApp2")
    End Sub

End Module
```